# Python, MySQL Deletiong of row not working

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

Hello I'm trying to delete a row with this code:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM produto WHERE prod_nu = %s"
data = input("""
    Type Data.
""")
cursor.execute(sql,(data))
```

The table produto does contain prod_nu and has an entry with prod_nu = 1. Which I'm trying to delete. The error says that I should check MySQL Manual about the syntax near "%s" at line 1.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: This should give a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a comma after data

```
cursor.execute(sql,(data,))
```

This will make it a tuple with one item. It currently will convert your string into a list of characters.

Or I think you can just remove the parentheses around data. Its been a while since I've done it that way, so I can't remember.